# Parsing python source into html - quotes

Tags: python, html, string, parsing

I'm working on a tool that parses python source code into a nice html file. Basically, it read a python file line by line, looks at the line to determine what's in it and then adds the right `<span>` tags with colors, line breaks and whatnot.

I got the general structure of the program, now I'm making all the functions that actually read a string and return an HTML enriched string.

I'm stuck on parsing strings that have quotes in them ie.:

```
x = 'hello there'  
if x == 'example "quotes" inside quotes' and y == 'another example':
```

My work so far has been enumerating a string to get the indices of single-quotes, return them as a list and then two while loops that put the right html tags in the right places. It seemed to work fine when there was a single quote in the string, but all hell broke loose when I introduced two quotes on a line, or quotes inside quotes or finally - a string made up of     '\''.

It seems this route is a dead end. I'm now thinking of turning to `.split()`, `shlex`, or `re` and breaking down the string into a list and trying to work with that.
I would really appreciate tips, pointers, and any advice.

Edit: Also, to make it clearer, I need to put HTML tags in the right places in a string. Working with string indices didn't give much results with more complex strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tokenize.generate_tokens`:

```
import tokenize
import token
import io

text = '''
x = 'hello there'  
if x == 'example "quotes" inside quotes' and y == 'another example': pass
'''


tokens = tokenize.generate_tokens(io.BytesIO(text).readline)
for toknum, tokval, (srow, scol), (erow, ecol), line in tokens:
    tokname = token.tok_name[toknum]
    print(tokname, tokval)
```

yields

```
('NL', '\n')
('NAME', 'x')
('OP', '=')
('STRING', "'hello there'")
('NEWLINE', '\n')
('NAME', 'if')
('NAME', 'x')
('OP', '==')
('STRING', '\'example "quotes" inside quotes\'')
('NAME', 'and')
('NAME', 'y')
('OP', '==')
('STRING', "'another example'")
('OP', ':')
('NAME', 'pass')
('NEWLINE', '\n')
('ENDMARKER', '')
```

From here, you can output appropriate HTML based on the type (`tokname`) of each token.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel so ignorant. I'm playing around with this in IDLE and this is the perfect solution.

Comment: I know this might be a stupid question, but why do you use .readline instead of readline() ? Doesn't that call a variable called readline from the BytesIO object, instead of the readline() function? I know it works, I just tested it out, but I'm curious _why_ it works.  Thanks again!

Comment: The [generate_tokens doc](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.generate_tokens) says its argument should have a `readline` method. Typically this could be a file object, but since I'm using a string, I wrap it in a [BytesIO](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline) since it too has a `readline` method. `readline` without parentheses refers to the method itself. Putting `readline()` there would call the method prematurely, return a string, and submit that as the argument to `generate_tokens`. That's just not what we want; we want the method itself.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast answer. I learned so much from this, I gotta wrap my head around it, it's fascinating. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

[Colorize Python source using the built-in tokenizer](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52298/) is an example for this kind of code (which uses `cgi.escape`). See if it fits your needs!

Answer (score 0):

Something like cgi.escape is probably what you want. There are also tools like BeautifulSoup and Pygments that do something every similar to what you're making, you may want to leverage them.